# Creating String Literal Type with const

Tags: typescript, string-literals

I'm trying to define a new type as String Literal using a set of const. Apparently TypeScript doesn't to like the idea. What am I doing wrong?
Here a simple case to recreate the error.

```
module Colors {

    export const Red = '#F00';
    export const Green = '#0F0';
    export const Blue = '#00F';

    export type RGB = Colors.Red | Colors.Green | Colors.Blue; // Error!
}

var c: Colors.RGB = Colors.Green;
```

The error message is

```
Module 'Colors' has no exported member 'Red'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> new type as String Literal using a set of const

You cannot use a `const` as a type annotation. They are in different declaration spaces https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

## Fix

```
module Colors {

    export const Red = '#F00';
    export const Green = '#0F0';
    export const Blue = '#00F';

    export type RGB = '#F00' | '#0F0' | '#00F';
}
```

Comment: Seems there is no way to reduce the duplication. One could type the constants to get some measure of typo-checking: `export const Red: RGB = '#F00'`

Comment: yup `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` 

Comment: It's only a little more safety, though, does not prevent `export const Red: RGB = '#0F0' // is actually green`

Comment: Thank you @Thilo , I read your note only after posting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a reasonable compromise:

```
module Colors {

    export type RGB = '#F00' | '#0F0' | '#00F';

    export const Red: RGB = '#F00';
    export const Green: RGB = '#0F0';
    export const Blue: RGB = '#00F';

}
```

In this way I can use one of those consts every time a Colors.RGB type is expected. The following code is now valid:

```
function foo( color: Colors.RGB) {
    //...
}

foo(Colors.Red);
```